# About measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $\{f_c(x)\}$ for all  $c\in [a, b]$ is a family of measurable functions defined on $\mathbb R$.

Suppose that for each $x$,  $c\mapsto f_c(x)$ is  continuous.

Show that the function $g(x)= \sup{\{f_c(x): c\in [a,b] \}}$ is measurable.

In my opinion only supreme of countable collection  measurable functions is measurable. but here we have uncountable collection.so where do i use the continuity of $g(x)$?

Comment: Everything you say is correct. But continuity implies that the uncountable supremum can be obtained by taking the supremum over a countable subfamily  (how?)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $u\in \mathbb{R}$, $A=\{x; g(x)>u\}$, $\displaystyle B=\cup_{c\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]}\{x;f_c(x)>u\}$. Show that $A=B$.

Comment: Very nice hint.